# insertion of many values radio button with one click

Tags: android, android-sqlite

im in the last part of developing an application that consist of questions and multiple radio buttons, i know how to insert each value of radio button apart, but now im trying to do the insertion of all values of radio button selected with one click on the button insert,  but i have this error : `java.lang.ILLegalStateException : could not find a method ajouter (View) in activity class`.

Please do you have any idea ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 
  int x=0;
  int y=0;
  int z=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db.open();

    //  RadioGroup  radio =(RadioGroup)findViewById(rm_25_1);
        RadioButton rad0 = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rm_25_1_1);
        RadioButton rad1 = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rm_25_1_2);

  //      RadioGroup  Télévision  =(RadioGroup)findViewById(rm_25_2);
        RadioButton tel0 = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rm_25_2_1);
        RadioButton tel1 = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rm_25_2_2);

//          RadioGroup  Réfrigérateur =(RadioGroup)findViewById(rm_25_3);
        RadioButton ref0 = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rm_25_3_1);
        RadioButton ref1 = (RadioButton) findViewById (R.id.rm_25_3_2);

}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
            // Is the button now checked?
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

            // Check which radio button was clicked
            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.rm_25_1_1:
                    if (checked)
                          x=0;
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                case R.id.rm_25_1_2:
                    if (checked)
                        x=1;
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                case R.id.rm_25_2_1:
                    if (checked)
                        y=0;
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                case R.id.rm_25_2_2:
                    if (checked)
                        y=1;
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                case R.id.rm_25_3_1:
                    if (checked)
                        z=0;
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                case R.id.rm_25_3_2:
                    if (checked)
                        z=1;
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
       Button bton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ajout_un);
       bton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 


          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

                ajouter(v);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Données enregistrées!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }

          public void  ajouter(View v) {
               db.insertcc(x,y,z);

          }
        });

  }}
```

Here is the XML file:

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/qm_25_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    style = "@style/question"
    android:text=".1.Radio :  "
    />
   <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rm_25_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background ="#FFF8DC"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rm_25_1_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:text="OUI" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ rm_25_1_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.81"
        android:text="NON" />

</RadioGroup>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/qm_25_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    style = "@style/question"
    android:text=".2. Télévision :"
    />
   <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rm_25_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background ="#FFF8DC"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rm_25_2_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:text="Oui" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ rm_25_2_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.81"
        android:text="Non" />

</RadioGroup>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/qm_25_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    style = "@style/question"
    android:text=".3. Réfrigérateur :"
    />
   <RadioGroup
       android:id="@+id/rm_25_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background ="#FFF8DC"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rm_25_3_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:text="Oui" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rm_25_3_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.81"
        android:text="Non" />
</RadioGroup>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/ajout_un"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="ajouter"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:text="ENREGISTRER"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your ajouter() method out of the click listener class and make it as a private member of your activity.

Comment: i tried this solution,the insertion is done but with only the initial values !! i am trying to change values according to the radio button selected , is there a possibility ?? thanks for efforts

Comment: so what are you thinking as a solution ? how could i insert the value of different radio buttons in my database.

Comment: finally it works, but thanks for your idea that makes the error disapear :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `ajouter(v);` call into `this.ajouter(v);`. `this` should refer to your OnClickListener class.

Comment: any idea, i really need to find a solution, i have to finish the application today and this is the only part left , so if there is other method i will try to apply it . thanks for understanding

Comment: why do you pass a view parameter in your ajouter method?

Comment: i specify the view concerned whish is onclick view.

Comment: what is the current behavior now? you always end up with the default values (0,0,0)? or?